# publishing self contained development SCD

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I'm using a `win10-x64` development machine to develop `.NET CORE` app.

I followed the steps explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/) for publishing my `SCD` app.

as the user machine is `win10-x86` I used the below:

package.json:

```
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x86": {}
  }
```

commands:

```
dotnet build -r win10-x86
dotnet publish -c release -r win10-x86
```

then copied the full folder `myapp\bin\release\netcoreapp1.0\win10-x86` to flash memory, then into the user machine.

once run at the user machine, I got the below error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments below the full `project.json`

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "runtimes": {
       "win10-x64": {},
       "win10-x86": {},
       "osx.10.10-x64": {},
       "ubuntu.16.04-x64": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors":"1.0.0",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "MailKit" : "1.10.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.0.1"
        }
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

the user machine has `.NET Core Installer DotNetCore.101.1-Runtime-x86.exe` installed, though i think this is not required for the SCD

Comment: [Scott Hanselman: Self-contained .NET Core Applications](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SelfcontainedNETCoreApplications.aspx)

Comment: [How to create a self-contained .NET Core application? @ SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40598874/3095779)

Comment: @Nkosi I did same steps once I started :(

Comment: @Deilan  I did same steps once I started :(

Comment: Provide full contents of `project.json` file. Have you applied all the available updates for .NET on the client (user) machine? What version of .NET Framework is installed there?

Comment: @Deilan the question had been updated to include answers of your comment, thanks

Comment: The project.json looks slightly different from the one @ Scott Hanselman's article. Have you tried following his guide **exactly** step-by-step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake, it was that I was running the `.exe` file appearing at the `..\APPFOLDER\bin\release\netstandard1.6\win10-x86`.

The correct action is:
Take the `publish` folder only, no need for any other file before or with it, only the files inside it, then run the `.exe` file inside the `publish` folder, i.e. the executed file path is:

`..\APPFOLDER\bin\release\netstandard1.6\win10-x86\publish\FILENAME.exe`