# Can ASP.NET CORE app be deployed on windows shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to host a ASP.NET Core application on shared windows host. I read the documentation and as far as I understood it can depend directly on the .NET framework, but other tutorials says that it cannot be done without the .NET Core (also my windows hosting provider said that it cannot be done).

Does the ASP.NET Core application can be host on windows shared hosting machine or additional configurations need to be done ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to distribute it using [self-contained deployment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40598874/3095779)?

Comment: So, @MarkSpencer, you are saying, "of course you can run .net core on "hostforlife.eu" vs on shared hosting in general? Is this a plug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can. But your host needs the [.NET Core Windows Server Hosting](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827547). Once your host has this installed, you can run your .net core app (full .net or .net core).

You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis).

Comment: Thanks Fabricio for the answer.
So basically until the host provider won't configure it inside the shared host machine I cannot host it there. Is it correct ?

Comment: Yes. It's very simple to configure, but you need it.

Comment: i see that, at the present, the most of share hosting provider do not support asp.net core yet or they only support old versions

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I have deployed ASP.NET core web apps to two different Windows shared hosting services successfully. I've had success with both framework-dependent and self-contained deployments. You can my instructions for doing a self-contained deployment here: https://birdsbits.blog/2019/02/18/publishing-an-asp-net-core-web-app-to-a-cheap-windows-hosting-service/

Comment: The link here was very helpful. Especially with the screenshots.

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20211025021721/https://birdsbits.blog/2019/02/18/publishing-an-asp-net-core-web-app-to-a-cheap-windows-hosting-service/