# Develop asp.net core api on windows and deploy to linux

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have developed a sample API in `ASP.Net core` in `Visual Studio 2015`. Now I want to know that how can I deploy this application on `Linux` server via `CPanel`

Comment: Take a look at [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40598874/3095779).